# Is the result of BCNF decomposition fixed?

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, bcnf

I have tried a few BCNF decomposition exercises and noticed that the set of decomposed BCNF relations of a large non-BCNF relation is not fixed. It depends on the method I use to decompose.

For example, `R(A,B,C,D)` can be decomposed to `R1(A,B,C)` and `R2(C,D)` to satisfy BCNF but also can decompose to `R1(B,C,D)` and `R2(A,C)` to satisfy the BCNF.

Is is really not fixed, or if I probably made some mistakes on my decomposition process?

Thanks.

Comment: There may be more than one set of decompositions that satisfy any given NF. That's true of all NFs, not just BCNF.

Answer (score -1):

No,the result of **BCNF** decompositions are not **Fixed**